# BigO notation of f(n) = f(n/3) + f(n-5)

Tags: big-o

What is BigO notation of f(n) = f(n/3) + f(n-5)? Can we just say
f(n) =  O(logn) + O(n) therefore O(n).

Answer (score 0):

the difference between time complexity and Big-O is:

- `time complexity` is an exact value which tells use how much does a program take time to be executed.
- but `Big-O` is an estimation of the time complexity in main parts of the code.

so, if you want the big-O you can say it's O(n) but if what you need is time complexity you should calculate a certain value.